# Running webtorrent js in browser

Tags: bittorrent, torrent, utorrent, webtorrent

So that the webtorrent works in the browser is it necessary to be running a webtorrent desktop server for example? Utorrent customers do not have this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webtorrent in a browser can only talk to other clients via WebRTC, i.e. it is not compatible with the TCP and uTP transports and UDP-based DHT used by real bittorrent clients, hence it will not provide the same connectivity as a desktop application.

Additionally browsers lack many other system APIs, so they can't match the capabilities of native applications. Considering that bittorrent clients are in the business of managing many large files and performing lots of IO that is quite an impedance mismatch.